# Toshiba C55D Touchscreen..

Tags: touchscreen, toshiba

Getting a new Toshiba C55D Touchscreen Laptop next week and want to run strictly Ubuntu and Firefox.  Want to rip every scrap of Microsoft off of it (it comes pre-loaded).  I'm a neophyte to Ubuntu and the finer points of setting up a laptop.  Do I first install the latest Ubuntu release, plus Adobe, gmail, etc., then go about tearing the MS junk out?If anyone knows the ansswer, I certainly would appreciate some info on this.  Toivo42.

Comment: Make sure you read [Installing on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/65926) before trying anything.

Answer (score 0):

1st, welcome to Linux!!  This will be a memorable day for you as I remember when I too broke free of the chains that Microsoft holds over their consumers.  By your comments I am assuming that you will strictly be using Ubuntu as your OS and if this is indeed the case when you install Ubuntu this will wipe your computer clean of MS.

You will then be able to browse the Ubuntu Software Center, find various programs that peak your interests, and most importantly enjoy the full range that Ubuntu has to offer!  You're about to start living life!